# how to search with max and min on two fields mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, search, max, min

i have this table(MySQL):

```
|id|min|max|info|
+--+---+---+----+
|1 |18 |24 | ...|
+--+---+---+----+
|2 |22 |26 | ...|
```

SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE max <= 21 AND min >= 21
```

Result:

```
NULL
```

Solution:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE 21 <= max AND 21 >= min
```

Comment: And what is the problem?

Answer (score 5):

There is no row with `max <= 21`. In both rows `max` is greater than 21!